# integral for range in x axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the area in the shaded region:

${f(x) = x^3 -2x + 7}$

${{{\int_{-1}^2}} f(x) dx = x^4 - x^2 + 7x}$

$= {[(2^4) -(2^2) + 14] - [(-1)^4 - (-1)^2 + 7(-1)]}$

$= [16 - 4 + 14] - [- 7] = 19$

But the answer in the book is $21{3\over 4}$.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to divide $x^4$ by 4.

Comment: You missed a $1/4$ when integrating $x^3$.

Comment: Please correct the expression you wrote. You should write $\int f(x) \,\mathrm dx= \text{the polynomial you wrote in the integral}$. What you wrote, $\int x^4 -x^2 + 7x$, evaluates to another expression.

Comment: @rubik thanks, I did not know this. What does dx mean in this context?

Comment: @dagda1$dx$ is called *differential* and is part of the integral symbol. Omitting it is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int ax^3 + bx^2 + cx^1 + d \, \mathrm{d}x$$

is

$$ \frac{a}{4}x^4 + \frac{b}{3}x^3 + \frac{c}{2}x^3 + dx + C $$

You have miscalculated your first term. Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sean said ,you forgot to divide $x^4$ by $4$

Also if you want to find the integral of ${f(x) = x^3 -2x + 7}$

So the result will be $\require{cancel} \cancel{\int_{-1}^{2}} \frac{x^4}{\color{blue}4}-x^2+7x+C$

$$\int_{-1}^{2}\left(x^3-2x+7\right)dx=\left(\frac{x^4}{\color{blue}4}-x^2+7x\right)\bigg|_{-1}^{2}=4-4+14-(1/4-1-7)=\color{red}{21\frac{3}{4}}$$